# implementing top-k *sparse* categorical accuracy metric for Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

Keras provides `categorical_accuracy`, `sparse_categorical_accuracy` and `top_k_categorical_accuracy` metrics.

I would like to define a **sparse** version of `top_k_categorical_accuracy`.

My tentative implementation,  is as follows:

```
def top_k_sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, z=5):
    return K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred, K.max(y_true, axis=-1), z), axis=-1)
```

This is modeled after `top_k_categorical_accuracy` and `sparse_categorical_accuracy`

```
def sparse_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
return K.cast(K.equal(K.max(y_true, axis=-1),
                      K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), K.floatx())),
              K.floatx())

def top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=5):
    return K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred, K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), k), axis=-1)
```

However, this does not work because the second argument of `K.in_top_k` should be a tensor of integers, and here I have a tensor of floats, and `K.cast` can only cast toward floats.

Is there a way to perform a cast to int in the Keras backend? Or is there another way to implement this metric?

Comment: `K.cast(x, 'int32')` should work fine

Comment: @y300 thanks, but no, `K.cast` only supports casting to float types, see [keras backend docs](https://keras.io/backend/#cast)

Comment: the code works, just give it a try